# How to float a div right

Tags: html, css

I want to float an div right like this
[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QuebF.png)

but all I'm getting is 
[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAcVu.png)

I've tried to align it with *float: right* and *position: absolute* but nothing has worked so far. If I try to align the text, it goes like this
[image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3M4qo.png)

My code is:

```
<div style="float: right; z-index: 10; position: absolute; right: 0; top: 0;">
  ...
</div>
```

I don't know what to do. I'd appreciate it a lot if you can help me!

Comment: Post your code...

Comment: `<img src="foo.png" style="float: right;">`

Comment: include your code on question section. Not on comment section.

Comment: @want2learn The OP didn't, that's my code. And it should be all she needs.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @j08691 sorry I didn't realize that.

Comment: Don't use `position:absolute`

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you meant? position absolute is not necessary on this one.

https://codepen.io/dev-james/pen/mzzJWg

```
.right {
  float: right;
  margin: 20px 30px;
}

.text p {
  text-align: justify;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something along the lines of the following?

**Code:**

```
<img style="float: right; padding: 0px 0px 0px 12px;" src="picture.png" alt="Picture" width="80" height="80" />
```

This should work. You can remove the width and height attributes if you dont want to customize the size of the image. If you do then just play around with dimensions until you find a size that you like.

If that doesn't work then give this a chance:

```
<img src="pic.gif" width="80" height="80" align="right" style="padding: 0px 0px 0px 12px;"/>
```

Comment: Yes, I've tried that but all I get is the result of the  3rd image. The text doesn't align :-/

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of `float: right`

*(click on `Run code snippet` to see it in action)*

```css
div {
  width:300px;
  text-align: justify;
}

img {
 float: right;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  margin-left:15px;
}
```

```html
<div>
<p>
<img src="https://media.wired.com/photos/5926db217034dc5f91becd6b/master/w_1904,c_limit/so-logo-s.jpg">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus vestibulum augue ut aliquet. Mauris ante ligula, facilisis sed ornare eu, lobortis in odio.</p>
</div>
```